# Trying to install lxml in Jupyter/Anaconda and getting an conda-script.py error

Tags: python, anaconda, lxml

I am trying to install lxml in Jupyter notebooks/Anaconda Navigator  (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/lxml) using the following command:

```
conda install -c anaconda lxml
```

and am getting the following error:

```
usage: conda-script.py [-h] [-V] command ...
conda-script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: lxml
```

I have installed other packages before. What could have caused this error?
​

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just running:

```
conda install lxml
```

from within your environment?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and now I get:

EnvironmentLocationNotFound: Not a conda environment: C:\Users\Laptop

Comment: Ok, did some more digging and I was not in the right place to execute your suggestion. It seemed to have worked now. Thanks for your help :)